# Php - how to read similar string from text file?

Tags: php

how can I read string from text file and check if exists or similar text exists with IF statement? (if string extist, dont update text file in case that the new information is the same as inside the file, if new info - update the file)

example:

```
 if(string exist) {
  // then dont do nothing because string exists
 }
 else {
  // do something like, insert info to text file
 }
```

thx

Comment: Please add the code in your question. It's difficult to understand. Also, what's the error in it?

Comment: @JakeRose please edit your question and add this information instead of putting it in comment - it's unreadable and less useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following code (not tested) to compare the contents of the file with a string. 
You can tweak the level of similarity by changing the minimumScore.

```
$textFromFile = file_get_contents($filename); 
$comparison = 'string to compare'; 
$minimumScore = 10;

similar_text($textFromFile, $comparison, $score); 

if ($score > $minimumScore) {
  // then dont do nothing because string exists
} else {
  // do something like, insert info to text file
}
```

Comment: What is `similar_text()` ?

Comment: If i can ask you just one more question please, can i do something to tweak it automaticlly (to be match exactly to the current string) ? thank you very much again

Comment: In what whay do you want to match it? Do you want to see $comparison exactly in the $textFromFile, or can the latter also contain more data?

Comment: @RubenBuijs I have string from one text file which always updates, so the max words length is approximate all the time, so i need to find a way to get the exact length every time its updates. I think the first option of what you've said is the one that I'm looking for:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_data = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
$mystring = 'mystring';
if(strpos($file_data, $mystring) !== false) {
    //the string is found
} else {
    //no such string in the file
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.